# PHP preg_match stops code execution without error

Tags: php, regex

Here's the issue:
This line of code

```
preg_match("/^([^<>}{\|])+$/", "Testing bla di bla and more stupid text text text")
```

completely stops my script.
If I take the last " text" out of it, it works and gives me a result.

The original code is not mine, and I'm not good with regex, but the idea is to check if any of the following special characters is in the text:

```
^ < > { } \ |
```

In my search, I found something about `PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR`, but setting that to 10000 didn't change anything. `preg_last_error()` doesn't help, either, because the script simply stops before it can output or log anything. There is nothing in the PHP error logs.

I have two questions:

1. Why is it simply stopping without any notice?
2. Is there maybe a better way to write the regex pattern that might not cause this issue?

Thanks!

PS: I'm running PHP Version 5.2.9, and the idea is to prevent the special characters from being saved, so I want to detect their presence and reject the submitted text.

Comment: What was the -1 for? I am not ONLY asking for regex help, but I am having what I consider a legitimate technical issue where no error is recorded, and I have done at least some research as I stated ...

Comment: You might try PHP's filter_var().  http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php  I'm not sure of it's speed.  If you know it's only text then one of the ctypes may also help.  Maybe this regex `[\^<>\}\{\|]+` would be useful.  Leaving the leading `^` and trailing `$` will make it so it only matches the symbols if they're both the beginning and ending of the phrase to match.

Comment: _"Why is it simply stopping without any notice?"_ That would mean you caused a fatal error. Define error_reporting and error_log not in your script, but earlier (.htaccess, webserver config, php.ini), and it will log what fatal error it encountered.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and answers. When it comes down to it, it was the regex code that was messed up (which is why I never like picking up someone else's code ;-) ), so thanks for pointing that out. I'll also look into the earlier error report for next time - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I avoid using regex as much as I can. Its too messy. There is always a better way. Check this out...

```
$chars = "^<>{}\|";
$text = "Testing bla di bla and more stupid text text text";
if(strpbrk($text, $chars) == false){
    echo 'Not Found';
} else {
    echo 'char in text';
}
```

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt It’s actually just taken from [a C function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/strpbrk.html).

Comment: I like the idea of not having to use preg_match for something like this - I've never seen strpbrk before, but it'll be really useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Both your regex is wrong, and it's also not super clear. This is a better way of doing what you want:

```
if (preg_match("/[<>}{\\|]/", "Testin{g bla di bla and more stupid text text text")) {
   echo "Contains illegal characters!";
   exit;
}
```

In your regex, you need to escape the special characters `\` and `|`. Mine is a little clearer though.

Comment: Actually you don't need to escape the `|` if it's inside `[brackets]`. Doesn't hurt, but not mandatory. Just sayin. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you've just got the `+` in the wrong spot. Try this:

```
preg_match("/^([^<>}{\\|]+)$/", "Testing bla di bla and more stupid text text text")
```

Brief explanation: since `+` means *One or more of the previous "thing"*, your code was telling it to look for one or more of the previous `(group)+` instead of one or more of the `([^charactersNotHere]+)`.